# Запятая после "может"

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

Нужна ли запятая после "может" в следующем предложении?
Может он где-то на пляже?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая **нужна**: "может" - сокращение от *вводного* выражения "может быть", которое обособляется.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_417&layout=item

Только в фантастическом контексте и с несколько просторечным оттенком  "может" оказывается обычным членом этого предложения:

> Выходит, здесь он не может песку нарыть. Может он [сделать это] где-то
>   на пляже?

А можно и намеренно перестроить предложение, чтобы "может" перестало быть вводным словом:

> Может он **быть** где-то на пляже?

Answer (score 1):

Да, поскольку в этом случае слово "может" выполняет функцию вводного наречия и может быть заменено на синонимы.

Иронично, что в подобных оборотах так же может использоваться и "может быть". Сравните:

> Может быть, он где-то на пляже / Он, может быть, на пляже. VS Он может
>   быть на пляже [,а может и не быть].
>
> Наверное, он где-то на пляже? / Он, наверное, где-то на пляже? VS Наверняка он где-то на пляже. [*В текстах примерно до 30-х гг. ХХ века можно найти и "наверное" в значении "наверняка"*.]
>
> Должно быть, он на пляже. / Он, должно быть, на пляже. VS Он должен быть на пляже.
>
> Скорее всего, он на пляже. / Он, скорее всего, на пляже. VS Он скорее всех оказался на пляже.

Comment: **выполняет функцию вводного наречия** — Почему наречия? Оно остаётся глаголом с модальностью неуверенности.